Door sidelight trim not coming out
i tried opening this trim from outside as there is nothing in interior to open sidelight . This looks like metal trim and cant see any silicone .


Highly unusual for the exterior to be the easily removed part, as that's a giant security hole.

Good chance the whole window needs to be taken out, before you can remove the trim.  Screws/nails/clips are usually hidden in the sides, where they are not seen with the window in the frame.
